# Top of program opening off screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I've written a C# WinForms app, I tested it on several PCs, worked without a problem. When I installed it on my grandmother's, the top of the program (including the minimize, maximize, and exit buttons) were cut off, what was worse, I could not move the form around to show the buttons, since to move a program you have to click the top. I tried alt > tab > move, but it tried to position the cursor over the top, which it couldn't since the top was off screen..

I couldn't take a screenshot on her PC, and now I'm not with her to reproduce the error. Do you know of anything that is causing this and any way I can assure it doesn't happen to other users?

Comment: Well, where is the form *supposed* to appear? You can control where a WinForms form appears on the screen.

Comment: What is the StartPosition of your project? Is the monitor of your grandmother to small for your application-size?

Comment: at a guess your application opens centered to screen and your grandmother's resolution is small, you can check the window rectangle and use SetWindowPos to move it to 0 ,0 if negative y

Comment: You have to focus the app then press `Alt-Space`, then `M` then press the down arrow key to move it down. But it sounds like your app's default form size is too large. You could make it smaller in the form designer before building a new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I re-sized my application and several controls. I think the bug was because the form was bigger than the resolution on the computer, and I had disabled resizing of the form. Now that I implemented scaling of controls on the form, resizing is enabled and form is displayed correctly.

All is well now :D. Thank you all for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small application which shows you how to set the left-upper-corner of your application to the left-upper-corner of the screen if it's outside the screen.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
this.InitializeComponent();
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
this.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
}
private void OnLocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
Screen screen = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle);
if (!screen.WorkingArea.Contains(this.Location))
this.Location = screen.Bounds.Location;
}
}
```

Comment: As a note, OP may still be missing maximize etc if window bounds are too big for screen still